# Creating multi-column constraints depending on column value

Tags: oracle, hibernate, constraints, unique-constraint

I'm trying to create a constraint on an oracle database that says the following:

If `column1 == someValue` then the combination of `column2` and `column3` has to be unique for all entries with `column1 == someValue`

I'm familiar with the concepts of unique and check constraints, and I've tried expressing the constraint with those constructs. However, I can't seem to find a way to include the condition. Which is why I'm wondering if it is even possible.

The table I want to create constraint for is created by Hibernate mapping the following class hierarchy (most of the attributes ommited for brevity):

```
class MyClass {
     String name;
     MyClass parent;
}

class MySubClass extends MyClass {
     String businessValue;
}
```

The classes are mapped using a single table strategy and using different discriminator values for each type. It's a customer requirement that for all instances of `MySubClass` the combination of name and parent has to be unique (column1 would be the discriminator value). It would be easy to enforce such a constraint on the parent class through a table constraint. However, that constraint must only apply to `MySubClass`.

There is the possibility of validating the data before entering it into the the database with frameworks such as Hibernate Validator. But since the validation would need database access anyway, a database constraint seems the more performance saving way to do it.

Comment: I am very glad to see an ORM developer appreciating the benefits of using database constraints!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this with a constraint, but you can do it using a ["function-based index"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm#sthref382) (FBI) like this:

```
create unique index mytable_idx on mytable
   ( case when column1 = 'somevalue' then column2 end
   , case when column1 = 'somevalue' then column3 end
   );
```

This only creates unique index entries for rows with column1 = 'somevalue', so other rows can contain duplicates but these cannot.

Comment: those cases aren't complete or I'm missing something?

Comment: @Florin, thanks - sloppiness is becoming a feature of my answers lately :-(